# Check a user is an admin on local machine in C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, credential-providers

I am trying to find a solution or winapi to check if a username is admin or not on the local machine.
The process is running under Windows Credential Provider so I believe checking the current user thread won't give me the value I want.

Please note, that I have gone through the other answers in StackOverflow 
which points to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389(v=vs.85).aspx) which evaluates current thread's user access token.

I have the username for which I need to find the access information, whether user has admin access rights on the current machine

Any pointers or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "Windows C++ API"? There isn't one, there's only the C [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516(v=vs.85).aspx). Tagging with "winapi" instead of "windows" would be more appropriate, because it's not directly related to the OS as a whole.

Comment: I have already updated the question based on your suggestion. I don't think downvote will help anyone without giving any reason.

Comment: Do you have the password as well as the username?  It's a great deal easier to check for admin rights if you can generate a token representing the user, but that requires the password.  (Without the password, it isn't even possible to check for admin rights in the most general case - if the account is in Active Directory rather than local, you might not have the necessary access to enumerate the group membership.)

Comment: @Bit_Pulse I didn't downvote. I think it's wrong to assume so, since the downvote only appeared the edit(s). That said, shame on the user who downvoted without a reason (unless the reason is obvious, which it isn't in this case)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, I have user password as well. and I am using `LsaLogonuser` to authenticate. This API has an out parameter `PHANDLE    Token` Do you think I can retrieve user privileges information out this?

Comment: Yes.  The token contains all the necessary information.  The only complicating factor is that the system might generate a split token; I'm not sure whether that happens inside LsaLogonUser or at a higher level.  Either way, you can check the token for the presence of the Administrators group, S-1-5-32-544 - if it is a split token, the group will be disabled, but it will still be present.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] to showcase the code you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *sure* it'll do what you want, but NetUserGetInfo has a field that's at least pretty similar to what you seem to be asking for:

```
bool is_user_admin()
{
    bool result;
    DWORD rc;
    wchar_t user_name[256];
    USER_INFO_1 *info;
    DWORD size = sizeof( user_name );

    GetUserNameW( user_name, &size);

    rc = NetUserGetInfo( NULL, user_name, 1, (byte **) &info );
    if ( rc != NERR_Success )
        return false;

    result = info->usri1_priv == USER_PRIV_ADMIN;

    NetApiBufferFree( info );
    return result;
}
```

There's also `LsaEnumerateAccountRights`, but (if memory serves) this only shows rights/privileges assigned directly to the account in question, not those it gets via group membership and such (but it's been quite a while and my memory's a long ways from perfect).

Comment: Thanks, Jerry. I will try to use it in my Windows Credential Provider and will update.

Comment: Instead of using the magic 256 size for the array, you should use the `UNLEN` (username length) constant.